How to design for API use cases that need different data from the same table?
I am building a web application. This application is meant to be a home for player rankings and tournament results for a competitive community. I have planned to do this in three layers: a database to store the data (PostgreSQL), a web front-end app (Angular) and an API to link the two together (FastAPI). As of right now, the database portion is nearly complete, but I have pretty much nothing for the other two.
I do have some experience in web development, but this is my first time tackling this sort of large full-stack project on my own, so I inevitably struggle with some things, especially when it comes to design considerations. One of those is, I am unsure how to structure some portions of the API.
The three most central pages on this website will be:
Player page
Displays basic information on a player, along with a table showing their competitive results. The table has info such as tournament (with link to tournament page), placement (ex. 12th / 52) and ranking points out of 1,000 (ex. 784).
Tournament page
Displays basic information on a tournament, along with a table showing the tournament results. The table has info such as player ID (linking to player page; this is not the serial database id, it is akin to a registration number), player name, placement, points scored (tournament-specific system) and ranking points out of 1,000 (for the global ranking).
Player rankings page
Displays the current player rankings in a table. Has information such as player name, player rank, number of tournament wins, and ranking points (0~1,000).
How does this relate to the API?
To answer that, it is necessary to understand how the data is structured on the database's side.
To put it simply, it contains, among other things:

A players table (id, name, country...)
A tournaments table (id, name, date, city, number of participants...)
A tournament_results table (tournament_id, player_id, player_name, placement...)

Essentially, if a tournament has 52 participants, it will have 52 corresponding entries in tournament_results.
What I want to know is if I should have two different GET routes for the Player page and the Tournament page, or just put everything in the same API route.
Two routes would mean something like /player_results/{player_id} for the Players page and /tournament_results/{tournament_id} for the Tournaments page. A single route would mean everything comes from /tournament_results/{tournament_id}. Either way, the Player page needs to read the tournaments table to get tournament name/dates/etc., and the Tournament page needs to read the players table to get player names.
Reasons in favor of two routes? They are both querying the same table (tournament_results), but the common factor is different (return all results for a given player vs return all results for a given tournament), and the specific list of fields the pages want are similar, but not identical.
Reasons in favor of a single route? Well... the bulk of the data comes from the same table? I do not see much else that would justify this option right now, but for all I know, doing things this way could be best practice. I am not sure of the best way to split this route between per-player and per-tournament requests, either. Optional URL parameters? Differences in the request body?
So. What is the best play in this situation? And are there other important considerations I missed?

I think it would make more sense to ask how to design this API in a REST style. I am not a REST expert, but I think without this restriction, web API design is quite arbitrary.

A tournament_results table (tournament_id, player_id, player_name, placement...) If this table has the player id, why does it also need the player name?

You've run in to one of the common problems of REST API design - if a request returns a list of related entities, should you be 'pure' and just return the ID's and make the front end do N+ queries to get the related data? Or should you be less pure but only require a single request from the front end? This gets even more complicated as you add more use cases, and you need to worry if you're overquerying.
I'd err on the side of 'be less pure and get the data you need in one request'.
Alternatively you could use something like GraphQL to get the data you need on subentities.

@JohnGordon Due to the way the ranking system is set up (country specific), tournaments may include foreign players that are not "registered" and thus do not have an ID, but the results page still needs a name to display, so it gets it from there

In the end, there is no "right" or "wrong" in this situation, so my advice can only be on a very general level.
You seem to be falling into the trap of leaking a certain design decision you made, through layers of abstraction.
Yes, you designed your database in a certain way, and this is fine. However, your frontend should neither know or care
about the design you chose for your database layer.
From the frontends point of view, you have two different entities. Players and tournaments are not the same, the
pages are separate, so probably the API used by the frontend should also be separate.
And if you follow this design logic, you will not have to rewrite the complete application when you sometimes choose
a different storage method.

"your frontend should neither know or care about the design you chose for your database layer" - uh, the frontend, API and database schema all share the application data model. They all need to know about player entities, tournament entities and the results relationship. Sure the implementation details of the database (concrete schema, with things like naming conventions, indices, surrogate keys, denormalisation) should not leak into the API or even frontend, but they're all informed by the overall data model design.

@Bergi What you call "application data model" is usually called "domain model" today, to distinguish it from a data model as in "how you store the objects." So yes, the frontend definitly knows the domain model, which I think I stated in my answer, but not the data model. Or if there even is anything worth calling a "data model" - maybe it's just a bunch of keys in a redis cluster or serialized objects on S3.

I feel the OP's concern, I know that having a design that is too flexible is bad, but having it too rigid is also bad, hence the anxiety of, " I should do this, but if I do this then it would xxx , what should I do then? " .

For this answer I assumed that the terms tournament_id and event_id are equivalent, although you didn't state that explicitly in your question.
As mtj pointed out in their answer you shouldn't design your API tailored to your database layer. On top of the points brought up it makes it harder to extend functionality, because the different application layers are coupled too closely. You might want to change the data storage method or implement a different kind of frontend later. The DB layer describes how data is stored and relates to each other. The API layer describes how the data is processed and accessed. This means that a request to one API endpoint often accesses multiple database tables, sometimes even other, external APIs to return the desired data.
With this distinction in mind, I suggest having at least 1 API endpoint per web app page. So in your case a very simple approach could be a REST API with these endpoints:
GET /players/{player_id}
Returns the data for a single player with the requested ID. The response is a composite object containing the player's data (id, name, country...) and all their tournament results (event_id, player_id, player_name, placement...). So it will access the tables players and tournament_results. Since the latter table includes the event_id of the tournaments the player competed in, you can use these to link to their respective tournament page.
GET /tournaments/{tournament_id}
Returns the data for a single tournament with the requested ID. The response is a composite object containing the tournament's data (id, name, date, city, number of participants...) and all its tournament results. So it'll access the tables tournaments and tournament_results. Again, since the latter contains the player_ids of the participants, you can use these to link to the respective players' pages.
GET /rankings
Returns many players' data related to tournaments. The response is a composite object containing a list of players and their ranking information. Since I don't know your exact DB schema, it might access all of the tables.

This example design assumes that all data is getting loaded up-front when accessing a page.

If you'd want to paginate the tournament results on your Player page for example, you'd make another endpoint:
GET /players/{player_id}/tournamentResults
This endpoint would only return the tournament results for a specific player, but not the player's base data. You can implement pagination on that endpoint (e.g. via query parameters , but there're also libraries for FastAPI (not affiliated) for that).
A similar endpoint could be implemented for your Tournament page, too: GET /tournaments/{tournament_id}/players
The /rankings endpoint could be paginated from the beginning, depending on the amount of data your API will serve.
Recap
Be precise and don't reuse the same API endpoint to serve multiple pages. It:

increases extensibility, you can add more endpoints later if needed, e.g. for pagination
is easier to document (although FastAPI does that for you)
is easier understand for the API user (which, currently is only you, but that might change)
is possible to add endpoints later without breaking existing apps accessing it. You should rarely remove endpoints, though.

Having less endpoints with many query parameters (don't send request bodies in GET requests for the reasons outlined here) that basically control how the endpoint works make these endpoints:

harder to test: too many variations/test cases
harder to use: it's easier to miss a parameter when accessing the API in your code
harder to change: fixing a bug or adding functionality is more likely to break the other use cases covered by the same endpoint

This doesn't mean you shouldn't use query parameters at all. But they shouldn't control what the endpoint returns, rather how much. Parameters restricting the result set are fine, e.g. to only return data before/after a certain date.
This seems to be the first API you develop, I've been in the same boat this year. And my original design changed a couple times while implementing it as I figured things out. Not much, but still. Don't be afraid to change your design to integrate new findings ;)

Essentially you need three endpoints. Not worrying about the paths for now we have..
GetPlayerById?id=

Returns a single player by id for the player info page.
GetPlayersInATournament?tournamentId=

Returns all the players in a tournament for the tournament page
GetTournamentScores?tournamentId=

Returns a list of playerId,Score for the tournament. used to add the scores to the tournament page
And maybe:
GetTournamentsPlayerIsIn?playerid=

Returns the tournament ids or full info that the player is in for the player page.
Now you can rest up the urls to whatever style you like. But our goals are:

Keep the domain models constant. ie Player/Tournament etc always have the same properties. You don't have PlayerWithScore etc

Let the db do the heavy lifting with the data filtering


A common objection to this approach is that it would be quicker to get PlayersWithScores rather than Players and then PlayerScores and then joining then up.
However this neglects to account for the resuable-ness of the objects which can be cached client side. You don't want to be constantly re requesting the player with random extras  PlayerWithScore/Tournaments/Address/FaveColour etc etc
